# aws query to find the list of inactive keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

This query has an issue with an error

```
aws iam list-access-keys --user-name "User1_aws" --query AccessKeyMetadata.Status[?Value == 'Inactive'] --output text
```

The below query gives me both inactive and active keys as I have 2 keys one active and one inactive but it returns both keys for the same user even I put the filter for inactive key only. Can anyone help me with this

```
aws iam list-access-keys --user-name "user_aws" --query 'AccessKeyMetadata[].AccessKeyId' && AccessKeyMetadata.Status[?Value == 'Inactive'] --output text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you.

```
aws iam list-access-keys --user-name "aws-user" --query 'AccessKeyMetadata[?Status == `Inactive`].AccessKeyId'
```

Comment: But this query will print the whole metadata of a given user, I want to get only the key like [ "ACCESSKEY"]

Comment: You just need add `.AccessKeyId` end of query option. (I update my answer, you can find it in latest version)